# Check if strings are composed by list of substrings

Tags: python, string, list, nlp

Using python I am looking to print all words from a list that are entirely composed of smaller words in a seperated list. For example;

```
list1 = ('ABCDEFGHI', 'DEFABCGHI', 'ABCABCGHIABC', 'AACFFFGHI') 

list2 = ('ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI')
```

From these two lists I am trying to get the final output to print; 
('ABCDEFGHI', 'DEFABCGHI', 'ABCABCGHIABC',)
As these strings from list1 are made up entirely of shorter strings in list 2. But the string 'AACFFFGHI' should not be printed as it is not made up of a combination of these shorter strings.

So to try and clarify, the strings I am looking for from list1;

- Should be fully composed of strings from list2
- Can include multiple occurrences of strings from list 2
- Does not need to use all the strings listed in list2

I've been struggling with this for a few days now and can search for strings made up of individual characters in a list, but I'm struggling to find the strings that are made up of sequences of characters. Any help would be much appreciated. Marcus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of, is by obtaining all [`permutations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) of the strings in `list2`. So here's one way you could do this:

- Obtain all permutations of the strings in `list2`
- `join` them into a single string
- Construct a `set` from the resulting iterable
- Take the `set.intersection` with `list1`

---

```
from itertools import permutations

perms = set(map(''.join, permutations(list2, r=3)))
perms.intersection(list1)
# {'ABCDEFGHI', 'DEFABCGHI'}
```